# wifi usb adapter can connect to one, but can't connect to another wifi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, wireless-access-point

On the desktop computer I'm connecting to a wifi using usb wifi adapter. I have two available networks, my home network and the one from the neighbor. When I want to connect to my wifi network, it says I'm connected but after like a minute it will disconnect and I can't connect again, I need to restart my pc to be able to connect again, and even then after connection is made, after one minute disconnects again.

So I bought a new wifi adapter hoping that I'll resolve the problem but that didn't happen I was getting the same error. Now, using my neighbor network I don't have any problems at all, no dropping in the connection, no disconnection, everything is running smoothly.

Furthermore, I have laptop right next to my desktop and I'm able to use my home network via wifi without any problems. I tried also forgetting the network, renaming the network but nothing helped. So my problem is really weird, I changed two wifi adapters on the desktop but the problem is still there, I can use other network but not the personal one, but on the laptop which is right next to my desktop I can use the home network. What do you guys think can be the problem?

UPDATE: 
I'm using windows 7 on both computers, the wifi was working fine on both computers until like couple months ago when I started experiencing problems on the desktop only. All the time I'm using wifi over the wifi device plugged in the usb drive.
If anyone knows how I can check the 802.11 mode, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Do they both work over wired connections?

Comment: Your desktop isn't connected to the wireless network.  You provided no technical information about the network ( 2.4Ghz vs 5.0Ghz, 802.11 mode, ect ) so I can't provide a technical explaination for the disconnect.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what OS you are using on each the desktop and the laptop. How was the desktop connected before using the USB adapter?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode with Networking?

Comment: I'll try that later today

Comment: Well we can't help if we don't know if any of the answers below where helpful. Did you try out any of the suggestions ?

Comment: All of the answers below are good and reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine has had similar problems with his Wi-Fi adapter. The culprit on his Windows system was a faulty driver for the wireless adapter. Updating the driver fixed the problem for him.

However, to make sure the problem lies with the driver and not the hardware, you could boot into a Linux OS (I recommend using an [Ubuntu LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)) and try connecting to your Wi-Fi network from there. If you manage to stay connected without any connection dropouts, that could be a strong indicator that you have a faulty driver for the Wi-Fi adapter installed on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the trouble-shooting option, it may tell you to reset router (your computer will provide you with instructions).

Just yesterday, my uncle and I spent half and hour trying to connect our computers to a trusted WiFi connection. Finally - after far too much humming and hawing - we did a reset. As soon as we did that we were connected and have had no issues since!

I think that preforming a reset is worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what channel is used by your neighbor AP and by yours.
Then try changing your AP channel;

please consider that depending on your location your AP and WIFI card might have available additional channels not available in US. (i.e. EU and Japan)